# ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34)

Tags: ldap, autofs

I am configuring my LDAP for roaming profiles using `autofs`, but when I run this command

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W -f automount.ldif
```

I get this error message

```
ldap_add: Invalid DN syntax (34) additional info: invalid DN
```

I have googled lots of forums but still didn't find the solution, hopping I might find it here.

Comment: The invalid DN can be in your LDIF file. What does it contain ?

Comment: This what my automount.ldif contains "# cat automount.ldif
# auto.master, example.com
dn: automountMapName=auto.master,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: automountMap
automountMapName: auto.master"

Answer (score 1):

Missing automount schema: you need to import beforehand

```
rfc2307bis.schema
```

which defines `automountMapName` attribute.